# multi matchs in espresso test android

Tags: java, android, testing, kotlin, android-espresso

I need to check view is display and is enabled.

```
  btn.check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .check(matches(isEnabled()))
```

can I use an array for this?

for example:

```
 btn.check(matches(isDisplayed(),isEnabled()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `allOf` method which matches all of the specified matchers:

```
 btn.check(matches(allOf(isDisplayed(),isEnabled())))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, can you check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405821/check-if-a-new-activity-is-started-with-espresso-by-click-on-vtn