# Check if a new Activity is started with Espresso by click on view

Tags: java, android, testing, kotlin, android-espresso

I have a button when click on this, start activity A.

```
 startActivityForResult(Intent(this, A::class.java)
```

I need to check in an esspresso test when click on the button, start activity A or not?

```
onView(withId(R.id.button))
       .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
       .check(matches(isEnabled()))
       .perform(click())

        // check is this A Activity start or not?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `espresso-intents` package.

First, try to add the latest version into your `build.gradle`:

```
   androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1"
```

Then, use `IntentsTestRule` to check whether your intent is started or not:

```
    @get:Rule
    val intentRule = IntentsTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun verify_FakeActivity_is_started() {
        onView(withId(R.id.button))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .check(matches(isEnabled()))
            .perform(click())

        intended(hasComponent(FakeActivity::class.java.name))
    }
```